# partial mock for class

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/features/) to do unit test. I know there is a function from OCMock which can **partially mock** an **object**. I mean this one:

```
[OCMockObject partialMockForObject:anObject]
```

But, I have a class which only consists **class functions**. E.g. `MyHelperClazz` class, I only use it like `[MyHelperClazz helperFunc]`.

I need to mock some functions in `MyHelperClazz`, but for others I want my test code to run real implementation of `MyHelperClazz`. So, I need to partial mock it. But it is a **class** not a **object**.

**How can I partially mock a class with OCMock?** If it is impossible, how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

A normal class mock allows you to mock instance methods of that class, and it allows you to mock class methods of the class. Please see the documentation: http://ocmock.org/reference/#mocking-class-methods

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with `NSUserDefaults` like so.

```
ClassThatUsesNSDefaults *nsDefaultsConsumer = [[ClassThatUsesNSDefaults alloc] init];

// Make an instance of the thing to partially mock
id partialUserDefaultsMock = OCMPartialMock([NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]);

// Configure the partial mocked parts
OCMStub([partialUserDefaultsMock boolForKey:@"interesting-key"]).andReturn(YES);
OCMStub([partialUserDefaultsMock stringForKey:@"another-interesting-key"]).andReturn(@"interesting-value");

// Set up a class mock and have a static accessor return your partial mock,
// this even works with nasty singletons.
id mockedUserDefaultsClass = OCMClassMock([NSUserDefaults class]);
OCMStub([mockedUserDefaultsClass standardUserDefaults]).andReturn(partialUserDefaultsMock);

// Test Away
BOOL isEverythingOK = [nsDefaultsConsumer isEverythingOK];
XCTAssertTrue(isEverythingOK);

// Don't forget
[particalUserDefaultsMock stopMocking];
[mockedUserDefaultsClass stopMocking];
```